# Use of Mutex in Qt Blocking Master example

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, serial-communication

I am studying the [Qt Blocking Master example](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.8/qtserialport-blockingmaster-example.html) to learn about serial communication using Qt. In this example, serial communication is done in a synchronous way and therefore, in order to keep the GUI responsive, a separate (non-GUI) thread is created to handle the serial communication. What I don't understand is the part where a mutex is used in the thread responsible for communication (i.e. `MasterThread`) to synchronize threads:

> Note, the transaction() method is called in the main thread, but the
>   request is provided in the MasterThread thread. The MasterThread data
>   members are read and written concurrently in different threads, thus
>   the QMutex class is used to synchronize the access.
>
> ```
> void MasterThread::transaction(const QString &portName, int waitTimeout, const QString &request)
> {
>     QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
>     this->portName = portName;
>     this->waitTimeout = waitTimeout;
>     this->request = request;
>     if (!isRunning())
>         start();
>     else
>         cond.wakeOne();
> }
> ```
>
> [MasterThread run method]
>
> ```
> void MasterThread::run()
> {
>     bool currentPortNameChanged = false;
>
>     mutex.lock();
> QString currentPortName;
> if (currentPortName != portName) {
>     currentPortName = portName;
>     currentPortNameChanged = true;
> }
>
> int currentWaitTimeout = waitTimeout;
> QString currentRequest = request;
> mutex.unlock();
> ```
>
> Under no circumstance should the transaction() method be called
>   simultaneously with a process fetching the data. Note, while the
>   QString class is reentrant, it is not thread-safe. Thereby, it is not
>   recommended to read the serial port name in a request thread, and
>   timeout or request data in another thread. The MasterThread class can
>   only handle one request at a time.

My questions:

1. I don't understand the need for Mutex. My reasoning is that there is **only one** thread (created in the `Dialog` class) that handles the communication and therefore there is no race condition and no need for synchronization.
2. I am more confused by the last sentence in the above quote (i.e. "Under no circumstance ..."). What does "[another] process fetching the data" mean? Isn't it true that we only have one process here (i.e. the whole app) and two threads (one for GUI and one for serial communication) and these two threads don't have shared data? And why does the thread safety of `QString` matter here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand the need for Mutex. My reasoning is that there is only one thread (created in the Dialog class) that handles the communication and therefore there is no race condition and no need for synchronization.

The application starts with one thread already active. That's the gui thread. As soon as you start other threads, there's *more than one* thread. The communications thread would be useless if it were isolated from other threads. Once it's not isolated anymore, a means of synchronizing access to shared data is necessary, and some data must be shared - that's the definition of there being no isolation. The only means of de-isolating threads is to share some data (if low-level message passing functionality potentially offered by the OS or the hardware is not used - and here, it isn't).

The synchronization is between the gui thread and the communications thread. The `transaction()` method must be thread-safe, i.e. it must use some synchronization primitive - here, the mutex.

> What does "[another] process fetching the data" mean?

The process is used in the particular sentence as an unfortunate synonym for a thread.

> why does the thread safety of QString matter here

The thread safety of `QString` matters, because a particular `QString` instance can only be accessed from one thread at a time, i.e. concurrency is not supported. Not even read concurrency is supported - some people think that just because they don't modify the data, the read-only access is thread-safe. It's not unless explicitly specified so. And concretely in this case: reading a given `QString` in thread 1, and writing to it in thread 2, leads to undefined behavior, and it's nothing hypothetical. You'll corrupt things.

> these two threads don't have shared data

The threads of a process are all in the same address space and thus share data by default. Thus the need for synchronization primitives. The synchronization may be implicit, e.g. if the threads communicate via posting events, the event queue is the synchronization primitive: it serializes access from event-posters to event-receivers, i.e. event-posters targeting a given thread are synchronized to receivers in that thread.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One more thing that makes the things more clear for me is the fact that I thought the `transaction` method is executed in the `MasterThread` thread, which is wrong since it is executed in the main thread. And that's exactly where the de-isolation you mentioned is happening.